# Modular equivalence of $a^{-t}+b^{-t}$ and $a^t+b^t$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

I was working on training for higher levels of mathematics olympiads and the problem was an application of the Euler-Fermat theorem, yet it left one computing: $2^{10}+3^{10} \bmod 13$ after having used reductions with $\phi(13)=12$ on both exponents.
We end up wanting to prove: $$ 2^{10}+3^{10}\equiv 0 \bmod 13$$
One can solve this by the method of repeated squares, but looking at the numbers, one has:
$2^2+3^2\equiv 0$, and $-2\equiv 10 \bmod \phi(13)$.

In general, I was wondering: if $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=1$, when does it hold that
$$
a^n+b^n\equiv a^{\phi(c)-n}+b^{\phi(c)-n} \bmod c?
$$
If this is the case, one has $2+a^{\phi(c)-n}\ast b^n+b^{\phi(c)-n}\ast a^n\equiv 0\bmod c$, but even though I looked into this, I was not able to determine more.
Any help on this?

Comment: Equivalently, your question amounts to deciding how many solutions (for $x$) there are to $f(x) \equiv f(a)$, where $f(x) = x^n + x^{-n}$.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula you have is 
$$a^n\equiv a^{n\bmod\varphi(c)}\mod c$$
For the problem at hand, you have $\;a^{10}\equiv a^{-2}\equiv(a^{-1})^2\mod 13$ for any $a$ not divisible by $13$.

Specifically, as $2^{-1}\equiv7$ and $3^{-1}\equiv -4$, you obtain
$$2^{10}+3^{10}\equiv7^2+(-4)^2\equiv10+3 \mod 13.$$